# Stop to download video/audio from site

Tags: php, jquery, html, html5-video

I have video sharing website. But I am facing a little problem with my site. When I am playing video. IDM (Internet Download manager) starts automatically. And video doesn't play and shows File not supported error (Error code 4) while I am using  HTML5 Video Tag. Please help to fix this problem either IDM starts automatically or not. If Error code is four how can I play video again and fix this problem that IDM cant start dowload video automatically . Thanks in advance and sorry for poor English.

Comment: What's the file type of the video?

Comment: Only mp4 files are supported for direct playback (to my knowledge). Could it be you are trying to play a different format?

Comment: Could you put a link for the test ?

Comment: http://tune.pk/video/5238224/just-for-laughs-gags-s12-ep-1mov IDM must start downloading automaticaly